# Why http request signatures are useful?

Tags: tls, http, digital-signature, amazon

Please provide pros of signing http api requests.
For instance, Amazon requires requests to their web APIs be signed.

If traffic is not encrypted, then a signature can prove your identity as a secret key holder and prevent tampering with request. But what about https? 
Why use request payload in this case?

Comment: Sorry, but I've read your question over 3 times and still can't figure out what you are asking. What, exactly, do you mean by "require their APIs consumers to sign requests" ? Without more context, I don't think anyone can answer this. It depends what the API is for, and the details of what's being signed by what key. Basically: please provide more details.

Answer (score 5):

You've kind of answered it in your question: HTTPS provides encryption, which prevents tampering with the request in a lot of cases, but doesn't prove anything about the identity of the person making the request in the first place (unless client certificate authentication is used, which isn't particularly common).

By getting the user to sign requests, they can be more confident that the user is who they claim to be (or, at least, someone who has stolen their secret key data).